# ASP MVC Routes without actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to leave out the action in url as I do not consider that to be a restful approach. Default routes should be:

```
"{controller}/{id}"
```

And then call the action that corresponds to the HTTP method used.  For example I am decorating a PUT action like thus:

```
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Change()
{
    return View();
}
```

However when cUrl-ing this, I get a 404.  So I'm doing something wrong, any one tried this approach before?

I'm using the MVC4 beta.

This is all I'm doing to set up the Routes:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: You are not showing code how you actually configured route, so it is hard to say if you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks Alexei, I've added my routing.

Comment: That makes sense now - and you have an answer from @danlundwig - your action name "Index" was not found in the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Change()
{
    return View();
}
```

The action method selector in MVC will only allow you to have at most, 2 action method overloads for the same-named method. I understand where you are coming from with wanting to only have {controller}/{id} for the URL path, but you may be going about it in the wrong way.

If you only have 2 action methods for your controller, say 1 for GET and 1 for PUT, then you can just name both of your actions Index, either like I did above, or like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

If you have more than 2 methods on the controller, you can just create new custom routes for the other actions. Your controller can look like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Put()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete()
{
    return View();
}
```

... if your global.asax looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
  "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);

routes.MapRoute(null,
  "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Put", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("PUT") }
);

routes.MapRoute(null,
  "{controller}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Post", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);

routes.MapRoute(null,
  "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Delete", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("DELETE") }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

... these new 4 routes all have the same URL pattern, with the exception of the POST (since you should POST to the collection, yet PUT to the specific id). However, the different HttpMethodConstraints tell MVC routing only to match the route when the httpMethod corresponds. So when someone sends DELETE to /MyItems/6, MVC will not match the first 3 routes, but will match the 4th. Similarly, if someone sends a PUT to /MyItems/13, MVC will not match the first 2 routes, but will match the 3rd.

Once MVC matches the route, it will use the default action for that route definition. So when someone sends a DELETE, it will map to the Delete method on your controller.

Comment: Amazingly this actually works.  I'm going to try out dotjoe's approach but this is a workable fallback.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki) nuget package. It has support for [restful conventions](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Convention-Based-Routing).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVC4 Beta, why not also use WebAPI?

That aside, I don't think the routing engine groks the various HTTP verbs... so, you're kind of stuck.  Unless you overload a single Action method for all of them and do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Restifier", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunate, but if that's what it takes then I guess that's what it takes.  I'm not using WebAPI because it thinks the webpage and the API should have different URLs and I disagree with that.  URLs should point to resources, not how to use them. That is what Headers are for.

Comment: Take a look at [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/), it might do what you want more natively.