# route controller action to just controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm new into routing, and have a hopefully simple question toward it.

Right now, with the default routing, I need to use {controller}/{action}/{variable}.
This will mean (if I want to use a {variable}), I have to enter my URL as `/Home/Index/1`

Is there a way to make routing only use `/Home/1` and send it to the `Index` action?
I need to use this only for a **specific** page, not all of them.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                 "Alert", 
                 "Alert/{id}",
                  new
                  {
                      controller = "Alert", action = "Index", id = ""
                  }
```

Comment: Check this link once... it may helpful...



 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839896/asp-mvc-routes-without-actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work. I surmise the reason your attempt does not work is that you have defined the default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route before this one.

You have to register this route *before* any more general ones as the routing engine sends the request to the *first* action which matches the requested URL.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Putting this **before** the general mapRoute made it work :)