# how search without action keyword in RouteConfig asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, search, model-view-controller

asp .net mvc search without action name only 2 level = controller and parameter

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Search",
      url: "Search/{parama}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", parama = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

result :
www.testdomainname.com/Searcha/keyword

Searcha is controler

keyword is parama

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839896/asp-mvc-routes-without-actions

Answer (score -1):

This is a good use case for the {*}

Check the multiple route section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#multiple-routes)

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "SearchRoute",
      url: "searchFor/{*parama}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", parama = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```